# Error when running JavaScript code — Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a modal carousel of images, however, I receive this error message when trying to run my JavaScript code:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Here is my code below, you can also view it at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Godclone/pen/RwroJqq). For some reason, in Codepen, it shows that I have no error in my JavaScript, but when I try to run the code on my computer, it shows me the Uncaught Type error.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 12</div>
      <img src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/9ba840fb-d9ba-47e5-abba-7ccec02324ef.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/20da1319-8182-44a6-80c1-7dccff732e59.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/6bdfd7fd-87fc-4cbb-9eed-949457bde059.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/4dc76189-2fa3-4199-b315-13e152db1489.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/1f7428f7-7431-46b1-8c75-51b711fdfcf7.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/56d2a5df-bf9a-4858-b67e-997bbd1484df.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">7 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/db924113-8946-4311-8088-6df6b6b32dc7.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">8 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/b3798866-9617-471e-aae8-049e7acbb9d3.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">9 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/139680f1-d515-4189-95b4-216d23cbdb19.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">10 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/65838a2d-052f-44e8-bd41-0c9bc76b5635.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">11 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/980fc83c-58e7-4ecf-9dca-8327d8c850d2.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">12 / 12</div>
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/113fbddb-eb40-4247-90e6-8dcaf90fc911.jpg"
        style="width: 100%;"
      />
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="boatBackground">
      <img
        src="https://buenavidayachts.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/9ba840fb-d9ba-47e5-abba-7ccec02324ef.jpg"
        alt=""
        class="logo"
        style="width: 90%;"
        onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"
      />
    </div>
    <div id="INFO" class="info">
      <div class="boatName">
        <div>
          <h1 class="make">Make: Sunseeker</h1>
        </div>
        <h3 class="model">Model: Camargue</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h3 class="title">More Info</h3>
        <p class="text">
          Length: 50FT<br />
          Beam: 14.60FT<br />
          Year: 1997
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="reserve">
        <a href="#" class="buy">Reserve</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

:root {
  --primary: #2175f5;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 860px;
  border: none;
}

.boatBackground {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 325px;
  box-shadow: -15px 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 -15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

@keyframes width {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 35px 40px;
  box-shadow: 15px 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 -15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.boatName {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.boatName div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.boatName div .make {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1;
}

.boatName div .new {
  background-color: var(--primary);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.boatName .model {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.boatName,
.description {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.description {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.title {
  color: #3a3a3a;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.reserve {
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buy {
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.buy:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.buy i {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .card {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .card > div {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .shoe {
    width: 100%;
    top: 55%;
    right: 2%;
  }

  .nike {
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .share {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }

  .share i {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 40px;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 70px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 490px) {
  .nike {
    font-size: 7rem;
  }

  .boatName div .make {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }

  .model {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .new {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }

  .title {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .buy {
    padding: 0.5rem 0.8rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .price h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .price i {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }

  .size {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  .color {
    margin: 0 6px;
    width: 0 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
  }

  .share {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }

  .share i {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    line-height: 35px;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 60px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }

  .info {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .buy i {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo {
    top: 7vh;
    left: 2vh;
  }

  .container {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("INFO").style.display = "none";
}

// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i = 0;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (slides.length >= 1) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I can only assume it's this line ~ `slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block"`. Have you tried debugging the value of `slideIndex`?

Comment: @Phil You are correct, I'm getting the error at `slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block"`. I'm not sure how to debug

Comment: Even a simple `console.log('slideIndex', slideIndex)` before that line would help but for real debugging, see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: One cause of getting the error in local and not in codepen could be that you are calling the script before myModal and INFO elements are defined

Comment: @Phil The slideIndex is equal to 1 when I tried debugging it

Comment: @Mario How do I make it so that myModal and INFO are defined first and then I call the script?